# Actionscript components events

Tags: actionscript, components

I have a project where I am trying to use multiple components in an ActionScript.  I have a numeric stepper and text input and a couple buttons.  The trouble is the events they dispatch in these components are similar (eg the "click" event), and I am getting a mishmash of scope problems trying to handle this.  What I did was create a function in my .as file that had a switch statement to catch multiple "click" events, but for some reason the numeric stepper still is not playing well with the others and keeps setting the instance value to "undefined", probably because there is a scope issue.

Anyway here is a portion of the code that I think is where there is trouble.

(vars: plus_Btn and minus_Btn are button objects, they increment/decrement a private variable by adding or subtracting the value on the numeric stepper which is called stepSize_NS.)

```
stepSize_NS.addEventListener("click", this);
plus_Btn.addEventListener("click", this);
minus_Btn.addEventListener("click", this);

function click(evt:Object):Void{
   switch (evt.target){
      case minus_Btn:
         command -= stepSize_NS.value;
         break;
      case plus_Btn:
         command += stepSize_NS.value;
         break;
      case stepSize_NS:
         trace("Step Size changed to " + stepSize_NS.value);
         //eventually this will do something else whenever the stepper chngs
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }//end switch
}//end function
```

Comment: Output of the 'trace' statement is Step Size changed to undefined"

Comment: OK I caught my first mistake... the numeric stepper doesn't dispatch a 'click' event just a 'change' event.  Fixed this but now the buttons are still throwing events that change the stepper's value which is really weird.

Comment: Discovered another issue.. the numeric stepper is throwing a value when it loses focus that sets the value to the maximum allowable value.  Weird but getting closer.

Comment: The second argument for `addEventListener` is a function reference. What exactly is `this`?

Comment: 'this' is a reference to the class itself, it is the container object of these components.  It is how you do stuff in AS2, which is what I'm using here.

Pretty much I have figured out it is the component itself that is behaving this way for some reason when the numericStepper loses focus it fires two events at the same time first is focus out event the second is a change event with no data.  NS is just quirky.

Comment: Then please forget my comment. You should tag the question with `actionscript2`, since it is completely different compared to ActionScript 3.